# how to dynamic linking for the .ane files

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.6, air-native-extension

I created a native extension. I can debug this application as an desktop application. Working well, there is no problem while using native extension classes. But When I debug for Premiere Pro, I get "

> Class com.extenison.samples.ANESample::myClass could not found

" error.
Do you have any idea what I'm missing while debugging for Premiere Pro extension ?
- I added .ane file on Native Extensions tab of Properties
- Also added .swc file on Library Path tab
- checked Package in Flex Build Packaging tab
- I can see .ane file on Package Contents section of Flex Build Packaging

Thanks

Edit : this issue is about linking native extensions. Any helps appreciated about this

Answer (score 0):

If we are creating .ane files for application that runs on some devices, that means we are gonna package our project and device will read files from package. 
My native extension (.ane) file was working on local, as desktop application because there was no packaging process.
was not working on Adobe Premiere because ;

- put .ane file under yourproject/src/ directory to some folder
- go to project/properties/Flex Build Packaging and checked your .ane file
- on same directory above,Click Package Contents tab and ensure that your .ane file is in the list
  I didn't do this:) But you do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this error and move on with creating an .ipa with you adt commands. The error is because of cross platform.
Though check with the points, You make the .swc as external reference from the properties.

Comment: thanks Jay, But I'm not creating an .ipa file. I'm creating .ane file.

Comment: Also I want to add this, .ane file,I mean classes, are working on desktop application. Not working on Premiere Pro extension application

Comment: I also work with the same, i guess you should check with your compilations of .ane check whether it has the platform added.

Comment: Also in platformoptions.xml or platform spcifications check whether you specify "iPhone-ARM"

Comment: Do I have to add "iPhone-ARM" for using this extension on Adobe Premiere Pro? I just added <platform name="Windows-x86"> .Thanks

Comment: Yes offcourse you have to add in platform options if you need to run on an iOS device it is must.

Comment: no, jay, its just not working on windowsx64 Adobe Premiere Pro. .ane file works on regular desktop application. But not on Premiere Software. I guess that there should be some packaging settings more than I did.

Comment: jay, WhenI check my Flex application Referenced Libraries tab, I see that my .ane folder has air icon.That means desktop application icon.Do you think the issue is this ? Does it have to be flash icon.

Comment: No thats not an issue it is because you have opened or referenced once using your Flex app.
Do you compile your .ane file using a console, by adt options??

Comment: One more thing i found is you do not need to add the .ane file to your project it is used to create the .ipa or .apk files as -extdir <path_to_your_ane> in adt command.
Your air app needs on .swc file, which is referenced as external code and not as merged code. make this cofirmed.

Comment: I need to add, because just few minutes ago, created simple project and just added swc as External but couldn't debug as desktop application. Then added .ane, worked as desktop application.Already addes swc file to my app as External. But not enough solution yet.

Comment: here is my adt command"adt -package -target ane ConnectionANE.ane descriptor.xml -swc NetworkConnectionLib.swc -platform Windows-x86 library.swf libAirExtension2.dll" and I have 64bit Premiere Pro. Changed command and descriptor to Windows-x64 and tried again:(

Comment: Hi Jay,I realized that when I click "Export Release Build" faced with "All native extensions will be ignored for AIR package type." and couldn't checked the "Package" tab.And shows "used" tab 'x'.

Comment: I read a warning in adobe.com about native exts.Says "be sure to use dynamic linking for the ANE". My mistake about this issue.Help about this steps ?

Comment: I am really stuck with the same issue, when i compile my .ipa on windows using adt commands, it throws error related to some framework that are available on iOS sdk 5.1. So may be when i created my .ane file on mac there where some issues related to linking those frameworks along with the and file.
Don't really know how would i solve this but will keep posting if i find some work around.